# How to modify build settings from Xcode scheme build pre action

Tags: xcode, xcconfig, xcode-scheme

I need to modify certain build settings during build time through scheme pre build action.. So how can I change the value of build settings variables such as Prefix header path or Provisioning Profile name from scheme build pre action.

Comment: I have a similar problem and the way I solved it is to store my variables in the `Info.plist` file which can be manipulated using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`.